# Getting 3.3 (V) from a 5(V) rail - Emitter Follower, or something else?

Tags: voltage-divider, rectifier, emitter-follower

I am using a Bluetooth module (RN-41 SM) that is spec'd to run at 3.3(V).

I can operate this module at 5(V) however, due to another part of the circuit, I need to run the micro controller at 5(V)

The issue I have is that the only rail I have available is a 5(V) rail. My idea was to use a 3.3(V) zener diode and buffer it through an emitter follower, however when I tried this, it failed on me. I have to supply at max 100 mA to the circuit.

I am using a garden variety transistor (2N3904).

I think my issue may have been related to biasing the transistor properly. Could anyone guide me on how to bias a circuit like this or suggest any other method I could use to supply the 3.3 (V) rail.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you need to go with parts you already have? If not, I'd suggest a voltage regulator. An LDO would be easy to setup and at 100 mA, wouldn't waste much power.

Comment: yes... thank you... i have realized that an LDO is the way to go here... thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not an LDO (Low Drop-Out) regulator? They're easy to use: capacitor on the input, and one on the output, and have much better performance than any zener circuit, load regulation-wise and line regulation-wise.

The [TC1269](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21380b.pdf) (just a random pick) has a 2.5 % output voltage accuracy, can supply 300 mA, and has dropout voltage of maximum 160 mV at 100 mA. Dissipation will be less than a shunt regulator as well.

The TC1269 is only 31 cents in 1s at Digikey. A zener + transistor may cost as much.

Digikey lists 3600 types which can supply at least 100 mA.

If you really want a voltage follower then remember that the output voltage is about 0.7 V ( the base-emitter junction voltage drop) lower than the base voltage, so you'll want a 4 V zener to get 3.3 V out.

Comment: A zener + transistor should not cost as much, but that is probably the only advantage, and I would rather have a LDO any day for something sensitive.

Comment: @Kortuk - if \$\Delta\$ cost < 10 cent then cost = equal :-).

Comment: thanks for the answer Steven. I will check out both options. I was trying to avoid another regulator to avoid redundancy, but I have gotten that suggestions from many people.

Comment: @Edwin A regulator like an LDO is a transistor with feedback, you are using a zener and a transistor, you are building a regulator, just not as great of one.

Comment: @stevenvh not if 10 cents is 1/3 the price and you make millions. But honestly, I consider the price close enough and the performance difference great enough to be worth it.